# Why isn't this text to table function working in R?

Tags: r

I'm trying to create four columns from one column in R, and I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49292019/how-to-create-table-from-text-in-r) helpful post on how to do so. However, instead of creating a dataframe with four columns and the same number of entries, it creates a dataframe with one entry, and each cell contains a list of random numbers that have seemingly no association with the original data. I've tried playing around with the code, but I can't get anything to work.

Here's the relevant code:

```
input <- data.frame(Treatment = c("Compost-0lb/ac 24in 60.96", "Compost-0lb/ac 6in 15.24", "Compost-20lb/ac 24in 60.96", 
"Compost-20lb/ac 6in 15.24", "Compost-40lb/ac 24in 60.96", "Compost-40lb/ac 6in 15.24"))

df <- matrix(input, ncol = 4, byrow = TRUE) %>% 
  as_tibble()%>% 
  mutate(V1 = as.character(V1), V2 = as.character(V2), V3 = as.character(V3), V4 = as.character(V4))
```

This is my desired output:

```
    output <- data.frame("V1" = c("Compost", "Compost", "Compost", "Compost", "Compost, "Compost"), 
    "V2" = c("0lb/ac", "0lb/ac", "20lb/ac", "20lb/ac", "40lb/ac", "40lb/ac"), 
    "V3" = c("24in", "6in", "24in", "6in", "24in", "6in"), 
    "V4" = c("60.96", "15.24", "60.96", "15.24", "60.96", "15.24"))
```

And this is the output I get:

```
head(df)
# A tibble: 1 x 4
  V1                              V2                              V3                             V4                            
  <chr>                           <chr>                           <chr>                          <chr>                         
1 c(39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, ~ c(39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, ~ c(39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45,~ c(39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45,~
```

Any tips on how to create four columns from one that I could apply to my dataset? I could easily have done this in Excel by now, but I'd like the workflow to be easily reproducible.

Comment: In the linked post, the `input` vector is interleaved, you have one value with date followed with one value with number. So using `matrix(...,ncol=2)` is a way to put all pairs of values on its own row. You're not in that configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this with `tidyr::separate()`. The only "trick" is that you have two separators, " " and "-", so you can match them both with a regular expression:

```
input %>%
  separate(Treatment,
           into = c("V1", "V2", "V3", "V4"),
           sep = c(" |-"))
```